# ASP Classic with SQL

Tags: sql, asp-classic

I am trying to pass on what the user types into the TEXT AREA box below, into statusinput, I have tried using statusinput=<%=request ("statusinput")%> but this does not work, how do I go about doing this?

```
<textarea style="height:40px;" name="statusinput" id="statusinput" onfocus="this.select()" rows="1" cols="60" style="color: #999999;" Onclick="openStatusBox();" Onblur="closeStatusBox();">Publish your news...</textarea>

<a href='editrecord.asp?thispost=<%=request ("thispost")%>&statusinput=<%=request ("statusinput")%>' target='_self' ><input type="submit" value="Update Post" id="statussubmitbutton" /></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Define "is not working", and clearly state what you're trying to do. You seem to be mixing client-side and server-side concepts.

Comment: I am trying to pass on what the user types in the text area box to the next page, Using statusinput=<%=request ("statusinput")%> passes it on but only "statusinput=" therefore the <%=request ("statusinput")%> part of it is not working. Hope that makes some sort of sense to you :/

Comment: I would suggest you don't use the text from a text area as a GET parameter, try using it as a POST parameter.

Comment: because that input tag is what you press to link to the next page.

Comment: all I am trying to do is pass what the user inputs in the text area box, to the next page.

Comment: Is the textarea part of a form?

Comment: no it is not part of a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few things wrong with your code.

First, you have a `submit` button within an `a href`.  Using `submit` without a form is nonstandard, but functional.  A standard `button` would be more appropriate.

Second, you're mixing client-side and server-side code.  The `<%=request ("statusinput")%>` code will be expanded by the server **when the page is first sent to the client**.  That is, the HTML that the client gets will look something like:

```
<a href='editrecord.asp?thispost=abcd&statusinput=' target='_self' >
```

(this is assuming that `thispost` is a variable in ASP that has a value of "abc")

To pass the value of `statusinput` to editrecord.asp, it should be included in a form:

```
<form method=post action='editrecord.asp?thispost=<%=request ("thispost")%>'>
<textarea style="height:40px;" name="statusinput" id="statusinput" onfocus="this.select()" rows="1" cols="60" style="color: #999999;" Onclick="openStatusBox();" Onblur="closeStatusBox();">Publish your news...</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Update Post" id="statussubmitbutton">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe I was able to use <%=request (statusinput)%> on the next page without having to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass textarea data from one page to another is to make it part of an form.   The fundamentals are:

```
<form action="YourNextPage.asp" method="post">
<textarea name="StatusInput">
<input type = "submit">
```

I'm not an asp programmer, but a quick google search makes me think that on YourNextPage.asp, you access this variable like this:

```
Request.Form("StatusInput")
```